# showing id selected div in url jQuery

Tags: jquery, date, url

I want to show the id of the current div selected on the url. I use this  [plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/02/fixed-background-scrolling-layout/) and i can't modify it to show the id of div selected in url.
  i need a help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the plugin's documentation to understand how to read which is the active panel.

Once you have a reference to `activePanel`, you just do:

```
window.location.hash = $(activePanel).attr('id');
```